# Uncuff someone in Street Fighter II : World Warrior after performing Guile's handcuffs

Tags: street-fighter-ii

Does anyone know if you can uncuff  someone after performing Guile's handcuffs in Street Fighter II : World Warrior?  And if so.. how?

Answer (score 2):

It is quite difficult, but according to [this guide](http://blog.analogmedium.com/2005/12/street-fighter-2-guile-bugs.html) you can do so like this:

> Charge back for 3 seconds then hit forward on the joystick along with
>   the Fierce and Roundhouse buttons. Just like in the Handcuffs, you
>   should try to hit the Roundhouse button slightly before the Fierce
>   button. Also, you should hit the buttons slightly after moving the
>   joystick forward.